# Handling errors and show loading progress indicator Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I handle the errors and show the loading progress of the data upload. I am new on flutter.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          newHome = Home(
              urlPhotohome: urlPhotohome,
              urlPhotoStreet: urlPhotoStreet,
              dateTime: DateTime.now(),
              isFavorite: false);
 
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('city')
              .doc(userId)
              .collection('home')
              .add(newHome.toMap());

          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text("Home save"),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900),
            ),
          );
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: const Icon(Icons.save),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try-catch.

```
 try {
      //show progressbar
       await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('city')
              .doc(userId)
              .collection('home')
              .add(newHome.toMap());
    //hide progress bar
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // Caught an exception from Firebase.
      //hide progress bar
      print("Failed with error '${e.code}': ${e.message}");
    }
```